# Selectively copy files from one folder directory to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a directory tree where names of folder matter a lot. Also i have a csv saying from folder1>folder2>folder3>foo.txt. folder1,folder2,folder3 and txt all in different column of csv. I need to keep the directory structure as is and copy the files that are given in the csv.

Approch i am trying is copied the directory tree and writing a python code to remove unwanted files. So there are lot of loops but I have over 415,000 rows in csv.

```
csv example:<br/>
pdf_no .   folder1. folder2 . folder3. <br/> 1 .  . abc. pqr. xyz.<br/>
```

This is the format of csv and I have no issue with extracting column data with help of pandas dataframe in python. Originally it was a .dta file I converted to `.csv with pandas. So 'folder1' > 'folder 2' > 'folder 3' > 'pdf_no'.`The 'pdf_no.' column contains filenames which is a number that we want in the given folder maintaining file structure.

So it takes a lot of time and whenever I change a bit it again will take much time and I don't even know if it getting correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sample csv

```
pdf_no,folder1,folder2,folder3
1,abc,def,ghi
2,xyz,pqr,
3,abc,def,ghi
```

### Sample code

```
import csv
import os
import shutil


target_csv = 'selection.csv'
target_dir = 'selected_20190828/'
source_dir = 'original_directory/'

with open(target_csv) as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f)
    for line_no, row in enumerate(rows):
        if line_no == 0:  # Skip the first line because it's the title
            continue

        pdf_name = row[0] + '.pdf'
        dir_path = os.path.join(*row[1:])

        source = os.path.join(source_dir, dir_path, pdf_name)
        if not os.path.isfile(source):
            print('not exist: ', line_no, source)
            continue
        target = os.path.join(target_dir, dir_path)
        os.makedirs(target)
        shutil.copy2(source, target)
```

### Explanation

You don't need `pandas` actually, all you need is

- `csv.reader` to read csv file into `list`
- `os.makedirs` to create folders (this method is similar to `mkdir -p` in bash)
- `os.path.join`
- `shutil.copy2` to copy file to a new folder
- `os.path.isfile` to make sure the original file exists

I have tested the code above. It should be working.

Comment: Thanks it works! But issue is when it throws "FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists:" because it tries to create the folder again. The folder is already created when first file is copied but when second files come into same folder it says already exists.

Comment: Used os.path.isdir() to check if directory exists. Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0):

You're needing the [shutil.copytree](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) method. Here is what you could do:

1. Read your CSV
2. Build the file path (with os.path.join())
3. Use [shutil.copytree](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) to copy the file and its parent directories to the target

Maybe you will have to add a `try...except` block to avoid an `OsError` when the target file already exists, or delete the target file before copying the new one.